# How to move object in a path while rotating it around its own axis?

Tags: android, android-animation

How do I move an object in a path while rotating it around its own axis as in the following image:

[image]

While this is what I actually get:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
AnimationSet as1 = new AnimationSet(true);
as1.setFillAfter(true);

float dist = 0.5f;
// The following is too slow just to inspect the animation
int duration = 5000; // 5 seconds
// Tried the following: RELATIVE_TO_SELF and RELATIVE_TO_PARENT but no difference
int ttype = Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF; // Type of translation
// Move to X: distance , Y: distance
TranslateAnimation ta1 = new TranslateAnimation( ttype,0,ttype,dist,ttype,0, ttype,dist); 
ta1.setDuration(duration);
// Add Translation to the set
as1.addAnimation(ta1);

// Rotate around its center
int rtype = Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF;
float rotation = 90;
RotateAnimation ra1 = new RotateAnimation(0, rotation,rtype,0.5f , rtype,0.5f );
ra1.setDuration(duration);
as1.addAnimation(ra1);

Object1.startAnimation(as1); // in my app Object1 is an ImageButton
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well changing the order of Translate and Rotate Animations Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to move object while rotating.

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        set.setFillAfter(true);

```
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);

    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .85f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
    translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);

    set.addAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    set.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
    btnRoll.startAnimation(set);
```